# How the assembly `dup` operator allocates space for strings and array

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I'm reading an assembly language book, where I encountered this line:

```
Byte 4 dup('stack')        ;20bytes: "stackstackstackstack"
```

How does this instruction work? How does this instruction allocate space for 4 "stack". How does it do so?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`4 DUP 'stack'` just means "4 copies of the string `'stack'`".

```
for (int i=0; i < 4; ++i) {
    AllocateSpaceFor("stack");
}
```

Comment: The `dup` operand does not run during execution, only encoded at assembly time.

Comment: This answer is not correct, and the code given is not equivalent to DUP. -1

Answer (score 5):

The `dup` instruction does not run during execution, only encoded at assembly time. As explained in, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h2ye0a0.aspx, `dup` specifies count number of declarations of the given value. Such that,

```
myvar1          db              4 dup('stack')
```

... allocates 'stackstackstackstack', *during assembly time and not execution*, to a memory address, namely `myvar1`.

Comment: `dup` isn't even an *instruction, and neither is `db`.  (Although you could call `db` a pseudo-instruction like NASM does, because assembling it causes the assembler to emit bytes at the current position into the output file, just like assembling `add eax, eax` would.)